# convert png image to animated gif

Tags: facebook, animated-gif, imagecreatefrompng

I got this from facebook

[image: He]

I want to ask if it was impossible to convert it into an animated gif. Of course I know I can split it into 4 part and give it to any gif maker, however, I want to get a bunch of facebook's emoticons, so doing it again and again would be a pain. Is there any software which can do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10139720/2151050

Comment: That was nice, but how will I get it as animated .gif image?

Comment: There's a lot of tutorials, Photoshop animation, gif makers software and online gif makers

Comment: Thank you, by searching, I found imagemagick