# css "Image()" selector is a valid / widely implemented standard?

Tags: css, standards, w3c

I was researching for my company project how to repeat in a background a section of a image (a sprite) without repeating all the image.

I found the css image() notation in the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#image-fragments). But it doesn't work on firefox 39 and I don't find any information of this notation on the Internet.

The only document that I found is in the MDN and was deleted in 2014. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image%28%29

Anyone has information of this notation? Implementors, state of standard, etc.

Comment: Im not sure what the question is but the standard, and whats implemented by the browser are not always one in the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the looks of it this was moved to css4, the new [spec is here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-4/)

There was also an [open issue on caniuse](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1336) to add Image() to it's data

Comment: can't find much on it, but [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876259/media-fragment-uri-alternative-in-css) there's also a [css tricks article/tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/media-fragments-uri-spatial-dimension/) on it, but everything seems to be years old. maybe there wasnt enough demand